# Can not connect with Windows 10 Remote Desktop Connection Tool to my Ubuntu 20.04 VPS

Tags: windows, ubuntu, vps, remote-desktop

When I try to do so I always get the following Error Message:

" The Remotedesktop can not connect to the RemoteComupter for one of the following reasons:

- The Remoteaccess on the Server is not enabled
- The Remotecomputer is turned off
- The Remotecomputer is not avaible within the network"

I have no problem connecting to my VPS via the Program "PuTTY" .

I have tried basically every Youtube Video that I could find and none of them worked, I also tried a lot of the answers provided on similar websites like this one, but none of the solutions worked either.

Answer (score 1):

Well, did you have xrdp installed on your Ubuntu box?
Linux OS did NOT install/use RDP by default. Only Windows OS do.

If you like to use RDP to a Linux OS, you have to install a RDP-Server first. and of course your Ubuntu needs to have a graphical frontend / GUI at all.

```
sudo apt-get install xrdp
```

does it for you.
Then check that port 3389 is open in your firewall

```
sudo firewall-cmd --add-service rdp --permanent
sudo firewall-cmd --add-service rdp
```

Answer (score 0):

I bet many people have struggled with rejected connections, so welcome to the club! ;-)

Just to make sure, I'll quickly define a couple of basic terms, please google them for more complete info:

- ssh tunnel = use your working ssh connection to forward other protocols as well
- RDP = Remote Desktop Protocol. Very well working and stable on Windows, unfortunately not always as solid on the Linux side of things, IMHO - but depends on what exact implementation you use.
- Port forwarding = A relay-function in a router. Traffic to port X on the outside maps to traffic on port Y on some computer on the LAN. Requires admin access to router.

I assume you have RDP installed on the sever you try to connect to, and that it is activated. Both Windows and most Linux distros have RDP disabled per default for security reasons.

If you first open an ssh tunnel using Putty, can you then connect through that tunnel with the RDP protocol?

Using RDP directly without a tunnel requires all network infrastructure between the RDP client and the RDP host to allow the RDP protocol. Perhaps also some port forwarding is required in the server-side router (if applicable), and opening of firewalls.

It is rather common to rely on the safety of ssh, rather than exposing many other protocols directly onto the internet. The reason is you want to minimize the attack vectors for hackers and bots.

An alternative to using ssh-tunneling could be using a dedicated VPN software (e.g. OpenVPN), which essentially also provides a way of tunneling your various protocols (including RDP) between your client and your server.

I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly. If not, please provide more specifics on what works and what does not work, and a bit more details on the exact environments you are using (cloud/on-premise, routers, software versions, ...)

Good luck! :-)

Comment: > An alternative to using ssh-tunneling could be using a dedicated VPN software (e.g. OpenVPN), which essentially also provides a way of tunneling your various protocols (including RDP) between your client and your server. A more comfortable way for RDP tunneling is using a https-Gateway like guacuamole or MS Remotedesktopgateway.
https://guacamole.apache.org/